# Save content's HTML blocks in post_meta or use makeup php functions

Tags: wordpress

I am write my plugin with have many HTML blocks makeup my contents in a post. Does save theme to wordpress post_meta and call them is better more than use HTML in php functions?
One of them like this:

```
function ln_main_tabs($post_id, $khoa_id)
{
    ob_start(); ?>
    <!-- Các tab chính -->
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active">
            <a href="#<?php echo ln_add_unique_id('ln-bangchinh', $post_id, $khoa_id)?>" data-toggle="tab"><h5>Bảng chính</h5></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#<?php echo ln_add_unique_id('ln-khoakinh', $post_id, $khoa_id)?>" data-toggle="tab"><h5>Khóa kinh</h5></a></li>
        <li><a href="#<?php echo ln_add_unique_id('ln-tatphap', $post_id, $khoa_id)?>" data-toggle="tab"><h5>Tất pháp</h5></a></li>
        <li><a href="#<?php echo ln_add_unique_id('ln-thansat', $post_id, $khoa_id)?>" data-toggle="tab"><h5>Thần sát</h5></a></li>
        <li><a href="#<?php echo ln_add_unique_id('ln-giaidoan', $post_id, $khoa_id)?>" data-toggle="tab"><h5>Giải đoán</h5></a></li>
    </ul>

    <!-- Nội dung các tab -->
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="<?php echo ln_add_unique_id('ln-bangchinh', $post_id, $khoa_id)?>">         
            ONE BLOCK
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="<?php echo ln_add_unique_id('ln-khoakinh', $post_id, $khoa_id)?>">
            ONE BLOCK
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="<?php echo ln_add_unique_id('ln-tatphap', $post_id, $khoa_id)?>">
            ONE BLOCK
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="<?php echo ln_add_unique_id('ln-thansat', $post_id, $khoa_id)?>">
            ONE BLOCK
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="<?php echo ln_add_unique_id('ln-giaidoan', $post_id, $khoa_id)?>">
            SOME CONTENT
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php return ob_get_clean();
}
```

Comment: If it's stored in the database it's going to be slower because you need to do a database query to grab the HTML content.  It all depends if you are wanting to update the content easily or not, if it's in template files then users won't be able to easy manage the content.

Comment: Thank you! I am thinking about ajax to slove my problem

Comment: You haven't even described your problem in the question you just asked a question which I answered.